# Redis wrong type error

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am doing a system in node with redis. The problem is when i try to save a new "array" in redis with rpush or lpush it drops the type error:

```
[Error: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value]
```

Here is the code i use:

```
redis_client.rpush(board_name, data.concentration, function(err, reply){
    if(err){
        console.log('Error: ', err);
    }
    else{
        console.log(board_name + 'has saved a new concentration value to redis.');
    }
});
```

I've made some tests and when the value of board_name is "ssas" (random board name name) it fails but for example if is "hola" it works.

Comment: Did you clear out your database after running your tests? Sounds like the error message is accurate here. Through `redis-cli` try `TYPE ssas`.

Comment: I've typed `TYPE ssas` and the output is none. i cleant the db too.

Comment: I'm going to trust that the Redis error is legitimate and you have an existing key with the incorrect type. Are you sure you're doing these operations on the same database number?

Comment: I think i am doing all the operations in the same DB.

Comment: Open a connection to the database with redis-cli and run `MONITOR` - this will print the commands sent to your db. Then run your code to see what it sends the server.

Comment: Itamar Haber GOT IT! I had another varible with the same name!!! thank you for show me MONITOR mode, thank you

Comment: My absolute pleasure :)